Resampling function produces audio with noise
I have function for resampling one channel of audio (as a float array):
int resample_and_save(float *audio_input, int input_sample_rate, int output_sample_rate, int input_num_of_samples, const char *output_file) {
    AVChannelLayout ch_layout = AV_CHANNEL_LAYOUT_MONO;
    SwrContext *swr_ctx = swr_alloc();
    uint8_t **resampled_data = NULL;
    float *audio_output = NULL;
    int ret = SUCCESS;

    if (!swr_ctx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate resampler context\n");
        return ERROR_NOTENOUGH_MEMORY;
    }

    av_opt_set_chlayout(swr_ctx, "in_chlayout", &ch_layout, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swr_ctx, "in_sample_rate", input_sample_rate, 0);
    av_opt_set_sample_fmt(swr_ctx, "in_sample_fmt", AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT, 0);

    av_opt_set_chlayout(swr_ctx, "out_chlayout", &ch_layout, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swr_ctx, "out_sample_rate", output_sample_rate, 0);
    av_opt_set_sample_fmt(swr_ctx, "out_sample_fmt", AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT, 0);

    if ((ret = swr_init(swr_ctx)) < 0) {
        ret = handle_av_error(ret);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    int output_samples_count = av_rescale_rnd(swr_get_delay(swr_ctx, input_sample_rate) + input_num_of_samples, output_sample_rate, input_sample_rate, AV_ROUND_UP);
    ret = av_samples_alloc_array_and_samples(&resampled_data, NULL, 1, output_samples_count, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        ret = handle_av_error(ret);
        goto cleanup;
    }

    const uint8_t *in_samples[1] = { (const uint8_t *)audio_input };
    int frame_count = swr_convert(swr_ctx, resampled_data, output_samples_count, in_samples, input_num_of_samples);
    if (frame_count < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while resampling\n");
        ret = ERROR_UNKNOWN;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    while (1) {
        int frame_count_flush = swr_convert(swr_ctx, resampled_data, output_samples_count, NULL, 0);
        if (frame_count_flush <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        frame_count += frame_count_flush;
    }

    audio_output = (float *)malloc(frame_count * sizeof(float));
    if (!audio_output) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory for output\n");
        ret = ERROR_NOTENOUGH_MEMORY;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    memcpy(audio_output, resampled_data[0], frame_count);
    ret = write_wav(output_file, audio_output, frame_count, output_sample_rate);

cleanup:
    if (resampled_data != NULL)
        av_freep(&resampled_data[0]);
    swr_free(&swr_ctx);
    if (audio_output != NULL)
        free(audio_output);
    return ret;
}


write_wav:
int write_wav(const char *filename, float *samples, int num_samples, int sample_rate) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file for writing\n");
        return ERROR_UNKNOWN;
    }

    unsigned char header[44] = {
        'R','I','F','F', // RIFF
        0,0,0,0, // Chunk size (to be filled later)
        'W','A','V','E', // WAVE
        'f','m','t',' ', // fmt
        16,0,0,0, // Subchunk1Size (16 for PCM)
        1,0, // AudioFormat (1 for PCM)
        1,0, // NumChannels (1 for mono)
        0,0,0,0, // SampleRate (to be filled later)
        0,0,0,0, // ByteRate (to be filled later)
        4,0, // BlockAlign (4 bytes per sample frame for float)
        32,0, // BitsPerSample (32 for float samples)
        'd','a','t','a', // Subchunk2ID
        0,0,0,0  // Subchunk2Size (to be filled later)
    };

    int byte_rate = sample_rate * 4;
    int subchunk2_size = num_samples * 4;
    int chunk_size = 36 + subchunk2_size;

    memcpy(header + 24, &sample_rate, 4);
    memcpy(header + 28, &byte_rate, 4);
    memcpy(header + 40, &subchunk2_size, 4);
    memcpy(header + 4, &chunk_size, 4);

    fwrite(header, sizeof(header), 1, file);

    fwrite(samples, sizeof(float), num_samples, file);

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

When I play the audio (even one-channel audio), there is a lot of noise on it, like there are missing samples. How can I fix it?
This is how original audio looks (24000 hz): 
And this is a resampled audio (48000 hz):


From your previous [deleted] question, I was going to mention that [AFAICT, with a cursory look at the documentation] swr_convert can return a "short" count. So, you should check frame_count. I'd add some debug printf for all input counts/sizes and output count/sizes. I think swr_convert is stream oriented, so it expects to be looped on. You may need a few extra input samples to be able to interpolate the final output samples (e.g. you may have to give it some padded zero samples). Maybe the second "flush" call does this?

Here is a [12 year old] bug report that talks about noise. I suspect it's about a true bug in the library (probably fixed by now), but, one thing to note is that when "flushing/draining" it loops https://gist.github.com/rectalogic/2431768 Also, notice that it's incrementing the pointers and decrementing the counts based on the return value of swr_convert

@CraigEstey I added a loop for draining buffer while swr_convert return value >0, but audio still has a lot of noise... though the final number of samples in frame_count seems to be right

You should post your updated code (this is okay because no answers have been posted). I've done video/audio encode/decode professionally and the usual: (1) wrong format (2) input buffer overrun (3) output buffer overrun. Again, use debug printf and print all pointers and lengths. Double check all byte lengths vs. sample counts. With noise, I'd bet that you're telling swr_convert that you have more input samples than are actually in your input buffer. Allocate more input space (but don't change the input count). Fill the extra with zeroes. If the noise is now silence, that's a clue.

For output, again, allocate more space than you [think you] need--try 2x during debug. Fill the extra with a known magic number (e.g. 0xDEADBEEF). After each output step, check the extra space. It should still have the magic number. If it doesn't, then swr_convert wrote too much data and it will "trash" the magic numbers (with real output samples). As an alternate, you could fill the input space with a generated sine wave. If the noise changes to a fixed tone, this also indicates input overrun.

You could run the program under valgrind to see if you're trashing the heap. Or, IMO, better, compile your program with -O0 -g -fsanitize=address,undefined. This will inject code that will check things when they happen. You can do either, but only one at a time (they interfere with one another). If valgrind/sanitize fails on normal size buffers but doesn't when you overallocate them, this is also a clue.

Note that the 0xDEADBEEF trick is what -fsanitize will do internally. But, since you may need to overallocate the input buffer, you're halfway there to doing the output debug yourself. Another option is to do things normally, but give swr_convert a shorter input count. Then, if it's using too much data, the data will be real audio (instead of noise). If none of these things work, I'd double check that you're specifying the correct format for both the input and output data. Actually, I'd do this checking first.

@CraigEstey I tried everything you suggested, but audio is still noisy... all buffers have enough memory and pointers seem to be set right, but I don't know about audio format... maybe the problem is in write_wav?

Could you show a more zoomed subset of the audio? Something like 0.01 seconds (with the same image size) of the same offset, for original and resampled audio?
